# Preimage of invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a linear map $A \colon V \to V$ on a finite- dimensional vector space, and $W \leq V$ it's invariant subspace. Then we have obviously $\operatorname{Ker} A + W \subseteq A^{-1}(W)$.

Is it then necessary $\operatorname{Ker} A + W = A^{-1}(W)$ ?

I can prove it in case $A$ is a projector. How to prove it in general? Or is there a counteexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $V:=\Bbb R^2$ and $A$ be given by the matrix $\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}$, i.e. it takes $e_1\mapsto e_2$ and $e_2\mapsto 0$ for the standard basis $(e_1,e_2)$.

Now let $W:={\rm span}(e_2)$. It is invariant, and actually $W=\ker A$. However, $A^{-1}(W)$ also contains $e_1$ (so it must be all $V$).

Answer (score 2):

What about a nilpotent matrix? For instance, a two by two matrix with a single 1 and three zeros?